# WebDriver - AssertionError shows wrong expected

Tags: java, selenium

The error I get:
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :0
Actual   :1

But in my code I actually expect it to be '1'

```
@Test
public void d_test2X4() {
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

    driver.findElement(By.id("rows")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("cols")).clear();

    WebElement rows;
    rows = driver.findElement(By.id("rows"));
    rows.sendKeys("2");

    WebElement col;
    col = driver.findElement(By.id("cols"));
    col.sendKeys("4");

    click_go = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button"));
    click_go.click();

    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("eyein-iframe")));

    Assert.assertEquals(driver.findElements(By.id("media-item-7")).size(), 1);
    driver.quit();
}
```

I expect 'media-item-7' to be '1'
It works fine for another @test which doing almost the same flow

Inspect:

```
<ul>
    <li id="media-item-0" class="plugin-media-item media-item" style="width: 22.5%; margin: 0px 1.25%;" data-index="0"></li>
    <li id="media-item-1" class="plugin-media-item media-item" style="width: 22.5%; margin: 0px 1.25%;" data-index="1"></li>
    <li id="media-item-2" class="plugin-media-item media-item" style="width: 22.5%; margin: 0px 1.25%;" data-index="2"></li>
    <li id="media-item-3" class="plugin-media-item media-item" style="width: 22.5%; margin: 0px 1.25%;" data-index="3"></li>
    <li id="media-item-4" class="plugin-media-item media-item" style="width: 22.5%; margin: 0px 1.25%;" data-index="4"></li>
    <li id="media-item-5" class="plugin-media-item media-item" style="width: 22.5%; margin: 0px 1.25%;" data-index="5"></li>
    <li id="media-item-6" class="plugin-media-item media-item" style="width: 22.5%; margin: 0px 1.25%;" data-index="6"></li>
    <li id="media-item-7" class="plugin-media-item media-item" style="width: 22.5%; margin: 0px 1.25%;" data-index="7">
        <div class="media-header"></div>
```

Comment: That is not solvable without the source of the page you check against.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [junit API](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html) you will see:

```
assertEquals(String expected, String actual)
```

So based on you saying you expect the value to be 1 then 1 should be in the first position(expected) and your findElements.size in the second position (actual). I think what your trying to do is:

```
Assert.assertEquals(1, driver.findElements(By.id("media-item-7")).size());
```

Comment: I've edit the first message to contain the elements in Inspect.
@cathal , with your code I do get the right expected, but the assertion fails though the element does exists (as shown in inspect.
Important to mention that above this test there is another test with almost the same code (except for there where I expect media-item-3, and this test pass

Comment: That is because driver.findElements(By.id("media-item-7")).size() will always be 1 as long as the element is found on your page. findElements finds all elements within the current context using the given mechanism and stores them in a list.

Comment: I do want it to be 1. That is what I expect. But for some reason the error shows that the Expected is '0' and that's probably the problem.
On another tests I also wrote '1' as expected and it worked without issues

Comment: if you expect 1, then change the expected value to 1. Edited my answer to represent this.

Comment: Yeah I did that. So I said, it shows the right expected but still fails and says that the actual is '0'. (Tried the same with my other @test and it also failed though it always passes with my code).
So in the problematic test, if I do '1, driver......media-item-7...size', it shows expected 1 and actual 0. And if I do 'driver.....media-item-7..size , 1'(as in my code) it shows expected 0 and actual 1.

Comment: Ah ok, then the problem is the element is not being found. Not related to the assertion. So its your selector is the problem, looking at your sample html, its difficult to see why 'media-item-7' is not being located. I see jsut before your assertion you are switching frames. Is the element you are looking for in 'eyein-iframe'?

Answer (score 0):

First check whether following web element is searchable:-

case 1:- Try below code without switching to iframe. If found then OK else try case 2
case 2:- First switch to iframe and then run below code.

```
try {
            wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);            
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("media-item-7")));
            System.out.println("Web element is present");
        }catch(ElementNotFoundException e1){
            System.out.println("Element is not present");
        }
```

- If web element is searchable, then only try
  Assert.assertEquals(1, driver.findElements(By.id("media-item-7")).size());
- I think in your case web element is not searchable. Also, your switching to iframe, so make sure your web element falls under iframe(Inspect iframe using developers tools and check whether your web element **media-item-7** falls under it)

Answer (score -1):

For some reason it just didn't find this exact element.
Solved by wait: `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("media-item-7")));`

- Can be solved also with "sleep"